# Pandas: Remove rows based on date comparison between columns in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am a complete coding novice and have been experimenting with Pandas. I apologize that this is a complete newbie question.

I would like to remove any rows where date1 is later than date2

```
    date1      date2   
0   1/1/15     3/1/15      
1   1/23/14    6/9/13  
2   8/4/12     1/9/11     
3   3/31/14    3/31/15
```

I would like the end result to be as follows:

```
     date1      date2   
0   1/1/15     3/1/15          
3   3/31/14    3/31/15
```

How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably best to use boolean indexing to keep rows where date1 is less than or equal to date2: `df[df.date1 <= df.date2]`

Comment: Here's an alternative which can be quicker, both to run and to type: ```df.query('date1 <= date2')```